# Best practice for right-justifying a Numeric in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the best practice for right-justifying a numeric in TSQL?

I have to format a fixed length extract file and need to have the Numeric fields right justified. (I am using SQL Server 2005)

I found [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=104823), which seems pretty straight forward.

```
right('            '+convert(varchar(20),a.num),12)
```

Here is the full Select statement

```
select
    a.num,
    fixed_number =
        right('            '+convert(varchar(20),a.num),12)
from
    (
    --Test Data
    select num = 2400.00    union all
    select num = 385.00 union all
    select num = 123454.34
    ) a

Results:

num        fixed_number 
---------- ------------ 
2400.00         2400.00
385.00           385.00
123454.34     123454.34

(3 row(s) affected)
```

I am asking this question because I found this line of code at work, which appears INSANELY complex (It is also removing the decimal and zero filling)

```
CAST(REPLACE(REPLICATE('0', 12 - LEN(REPLACE(CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),@DD8DBAMT) AS VARCHAR),'.',''))) 
+ CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),@DD8DBAMT) AS VARCHAR),'.','') AS VARCHAR(12))
```

**Updated:**

Daniel Pratt's idea of using a function got me looking at [SQL#](http://www.sqlsharp.com/) (which we own). It has a function called [PadLeft](http://www.sqlsharp.com/features/), which surprisingly enough had the same parameters and functionality as Daniel Pratt's fn_PadRight function defined in his answer below.

Here is how to use SQL# function:

```
DECLARE @F6D2 AS DECIMAL(8,2)
SET @F6D2 = 0
SQL#.String_PadLeft(@F6D2,9,' ')
SQL#.String_PadLeft(123.400,9,' ')
SQL#.String_PadLeft('abc',9,' ')
```

It can take both numbers and strings.

Comment: Is there a reason you are wanting to do this right justification in your tsql code and not in the area of output (i.e. a website, reporting services, etc.?) Trying to hammer out layout in tsql code itself is a big WTF waiting to happen, IMHO.

Comment: @TheTXI: Read more carefully. There is no "area of output" other than an extract *file*. How does an extract file perform formatting of the data?

Comment: The original question did say that this was for an "extract" file. As such, it doesn't sound like he is mixing data and presentation.

Comment: I would recommend using a normal sort of select statement and then generating the extract file using a sprintf statement for each row or something of the like.  It really will keep you sane....

Comment: I would agree with both of you but this is how other extracts where created in our company. I am new to creating extracts out of SQL Server and I am relying on the expertise of the other .NET/SQL programmers in the company. I know about DTS/SSIS but they ran into issues using them.

Comment: @gbn You are correct. They are using bcp to extract the data from a table. One column will hold the whole record.

Comment: @gbn Then they do bcp similar to the following: 'bcp "EXEC  [BeneSysNetOutput].[Vacation].[GetExtractData] ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ClientID) + ',' + @SettlementDate +  ' " queryout "' + @ExtractFile + '" -c -T -x -e'

Comment: @gbn I know this is pretty backward but that is what they do.

Comment: No comment. It works so good enough :-). Check out STR in my answer below to see if it's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can suggest to help with the "insane complexity" is to encapsulate it in one or more functions. Here's a somewhat modified version of something we're using:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_PadRight]
(
    @Value nvarchar(4000)
    ,@NewLength int
    ,@PadChar nchar(1) = ' '
) RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ValueLength int
    SET @ValueLength = LEN(@Value)

    IF (@NewLength > @ValueLength) BEGIN
        SET @Value = @Value + REPLICATE(@PadChar, @NewLength - @ValueLength)
    END

    RETURN @Value
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_FormatAmountDE]
(
    @Value money
) RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN [dbo].[fn_PadRight](REPLACE(CAST(@Value AS varchar), '.', ''), 12, '0')
END
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

Your not going like my answer, but the best practice is to do this someplace other then SQL. SQL is meant to store retrieve and process data not visualize it. Not format it for display. You'd be much better IMHO having a console application that pulls the data then generates the file.

But with that said when I did this before, I did it like this:

```
declare @num int
set @num=1555
select replicate(' ',20-len(cast(@num as varchar))) + cast(@num as varchar)
```

Hardcoding spaces so nasty, this will probally break for a huge number but then again if your generating a fixed file your going generate garbage anyways for a huge number

## Edit

Ken I did read the ops post, and yes he is formatting the data into a fixed width file. The point is that you should do formatting in an application tier, not in SQL. Yes there is no one visually looking at the data, but I guess I feel like you are still formating the data, we are probally splitting hairs.

Comment: @Josh: Read the post before answering. There is no "visualization" or display here - the OP is producing an extract *file*. Please explain how a text file does presentation or formatting of data.

Comment: I doubt the file is being created through the application, most of these things ar done through jobs or SSIS pacakages or the like and never even get close to the application.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in general would be to have the database return data, and to have the presentation layer format the data. You shouldn't be formatting data in the database.

---

I now what the comment points out - you're creating an extract file. I still wonder how you're going to get the data out of SQL Server and into the file. Surely SQL Server isn't creating the disk file through a query?

I still recommend separating the data from its presentation, even if that presentation is a fixed-length file. This is thie kind of thing we used to do "in the good old days", but should avoid today, now that we have computers fast enough to deal with things like separation of concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to format the data in the database.

Comment: Although that was my first thought from the post subject, he specifically said he was producing a fixed length extract *file*.